# Mono GTK# Text View - how to get user input?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am trying to write a rather simple note-taking app for Elementary OS. It is my first time in C#/Mono world. I encoutered this problem.

Is it possible to take input from a Text View? I know how to do it from Entry... but how to get it from Text View?

Comment: Can you show your current code for creating the `TextView` that doesn't yet accept (?) any input, please?

Comment: I am working in MonoDevelop IDE, so I created the UI layout via Designer. And now I am stuck.

Comment: I use `string str = entry.Text;` to get data from Entry. `textview.Text' does not exist so `string str = textview.Text` does not work either.

Comment: Have you looked into the example that is provided in the [`TextView` docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TextView)? They use a buffer object as a data model and access the text in that object.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that. I was reading that code for ages before posting here but I guess I needed someone to point me to the right direction. It works now. Can you post it as an answer? I will set it as the correct one.

Comment: Done. I hope that is sufficiently explained to be useful also to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to the simpler `Entry` class for rather short texts, [`TextView` class](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TextView) is structured in a way so the data is stored in a separate data model object. That data model, a text buffer, is accessible by means of the [`Buffer` property](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aGtk.TextView.Buffer).

The [`TextBuffer.Text` property of that object](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=P%3aGtk.TextBuffer.Text) allows you to retrieve or modify the text shown in the `TextView`. Refer to the example in the [`TextView` docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TextView) to see its exemplary use.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how to Cut, Copy, Paste, select all text in a TextView/TextBuffer? Intellisense in MonoDevelop (C#) is not showing any of those methods nor is the documentation saying anything about it either. How can we do that?

Comment: @jay_t55: It seems that problem is unrelated to this SO question - please create a new SO question for your issue. That will also make the question (and any answers to it) easier to find for future visitors who are facing the same problem as you.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at that question? I already posted one an hour ago. I've been scouring the web for... something. But I'm just not finding anything. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547425/how-do-i-cut-copy-paste-and-select-all-in-a-textview-control

Answer (score -1):

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Test.txt");
sw.Write(textview3.Buffer.Text); //Write textview1 text to file
//textview3.Buffer.Text = "Saved to file !"; //Notify user
sw.Close();
```