# How do I cut, copy, paste and select all in a TextView control?

Tags: c#, linux, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm trying to cut, copy, paste and select all with the TextView Gtk control. Why the TextView control? Cause I can't seem to get the bloody TextEditor control to go multiline!

Anyway... How do I:

**Cut** text from the TextView control?

**Copy** text from the TextView control?

**Paste** text into the TextView control?

**Select All** text in the TextView control?

---

Here's what I've tried:
1 hour of googling.

and this:

```
TextView tv = ...;
TextIter start, end;
if (tv.Buffer.GetSelectionBounds(start, end)) {
  String selected = tv.Buffer.GetText(start, end);
  Clipboard clipboard = tv.GetClipboard(Gdk.Selection.Clipboard);
  clipboard.Text = selected;
}
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308501/gtk-textview-copy-and-paste - but that obviously doesn't work (hence my question).

I've also found this: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TextView The Mono GTK C# docs. There is so much stuff that just seems to be non-existent.

Comment: Still no answers? Please don't tell me that nobody knows how to Cut, Copy, Paste or Select All in a MonoDevelop C# app... The thought of that is truly horrifying.

Answer (score 9):

Basically you should work with Underlying `TextBuffer` from your `TextView`.

### Selection

To Cut, Copy and Paste, First we should select the part we intended to Copy (or check and see if the buffer already has some selection or not), to select a part we should get an Iterator of type `TextIter` from buffer, here is how we can do it:

Here is an example for **SelectAll**:

```
var start = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);

var end = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
end.ForwardToEnd ();

textview.Buffer.SelectRange (start, end);
```

Here is an example is for selecting range [2,4] from text:

```
var start = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
start.ForwardChars (2);

var end = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
end.ForwardChars (4);

textview.Buffer.SelectRange (start, end);
```

`TextIter` have extensive methods for range selection for example `ForwardChars()` has a twin method `BackwardChars()`.

To check if our `TextBuffer` has any selection we should use `HasSelection` Property:

```
var hasSelection = textview.Buffer.HasSelection;
```

### Working with Clipboard

Now that we have a selected text we can simply use it with Clipboard actions.

Here is a sample for **Cutting** selected range [2,4]:

```
 var clipboard = textview.GetClipboard (Gdk.Selection.Clipboard);

var start = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
start.ForwardChars (2);

var end = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
end.ForwardChars (4);

textview.Buffer.SelectRange (start, end);

textview.Buffer.CutClipboard (clipboard, true);
```

**Copying** is very similar to **Cutting** we should only replace `CutClipboard` with `CopyClipboard` :

Here is a sample for **Copying** selected range [2,4]:

```
 var clipboard = textview.GetClipboard (Gdk.Selection.Clipboard);

var start = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
start.ForwardChars (2);

var end = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
end.ForwardChars (4);

textview.Buffer.SelectRange (start, end);

textview.Buffer.CopyClipboard (clipboard, true);
```

and finally **Pasting** something from clipboard is very similar to **Cutting/Copying**

Here is an example of **Pasting** some text from Clipboard to location 0:

```
var pasteLocation=textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
textview.Buffer.SelectRange (pasteLocation, pasteLocation);

textview.Buffer.PasteClipboard (clipboard);
```

### Final Example:

As a final example, we set text to **123456** and then cut **34** from it and paste it at the beginning, the final text should be like **341256** :

```
void TextViewSample ()
{
    textview.Buffer.Text = "123456";
    var clipboard = textview.GetClipboard (Gdk.Selection.Clipboard);
    var start = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
    start.ForwardChars (2);
    var end = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
    end.ForwardChars (4);
    textview.Buffer.SelectRange (start, end);
    var hasSelection = textview.Buffer.HasSelection;
    textview.Buffer.CutClipboard (clipboard, true);
    var pasteLocation = textview.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset (0);
    textview.Buffer.SelectRange (pasteLocation, pasteLocation);
    textview.Buffer.PasteClipboard (clipboard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some buttons for do this!actually button1(copy),button2(paste) and etc
then you can read user input (TextField**.Text**) and then **put** it in a **array**
after that you can show your array for output(paste)
and also for copy/paste selected parts of inputs(not all),you can store indexes(from which index until end index are selected) and read/write data between that indexes(selected index) and put user input in array and Enjoy it!
i'm not a c# Programmer,but i try to make you understand what you should to do.i hope so
good luck